# "catkin build" not working in ros noetic via docker

Tags: docker, ros

I am using ros noetic via docker on windows.

The command "catkin build" returns "bash: catkin: command not found".

I tried:

- sudo pip3 install git+https://github.com/catkin/catkin_tools.git
- sudo apt-get install python3-catkin-tools

nothing worked.

Can someone help ?

Comment: Are you using the official ROS docker image? Or did you build one yourself?

Comment: can you please copy the output of `docker inspect <image or container name>`. Probably your `entrypoint` is missing

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the source part for the system to know what `catkin` is. Try doing `source /opt/ros/noetic/setup.bash` and the running the command `catkin build` in your workspace.